# design:paramtypes is empty in a Jest unit test while testing a decorator

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to unit test a decorator that I wrote. The problem is that `Reflect.getMetadata("design:paramtypes", type)` returns nothing in the decorator.

But when I execute the code instead, it returns an array. So it seems that my configuration is incorrect in some way.

I've imported `reflect-metadata` in a typescript file which is executed in `setupFilesAfterEnv`.

My jest config:

```json
module.exports = {
  roots: ['<rootDir>'],
  testMatch: [
    "<rootDir>/tests/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)",
    "**/?(*.)+(_spec|_test).+(ts|tsx|js)"
  ],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    '<rootDir>/src/jest/StandardLogger.ts',
    '<rootDir>/src/jest/startup.ts'],
  "verbose": true,
  "testURL": "http://localhost/"
}
```

Decorator:

```
export function someDecorator() {
  return function <T>(target: Type<T>) {
    console.log('params', Reflect.getMetadata("design:paramtypes", target));
  };
}
```

Complete code:

```js
import "reflect-metadata";

export interface Type<T> {
    new(...args: any[]): T;
}

export function someDecorator() {
    return function <T>(target: Type<T>) {
        console.log('params', Reflect.getMetadata("design:paramtypes", target));
    };
}

@someDecorator()
export class SomeClass {
    invoke() {
        console.log('hello');
    }
}

describe("Container", () => {


    test("reproduce", () => {
        var actual = new SomeClass();


        actual.invoke();

    });
});
```

Comment: What test, what decorator? Pease give a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'ved added code. It logs "params undefined"